# How to transfer keys and values ​from map to another map?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to transfer keys and values ​​to another map, but at the same time leave the old keys and values.

How can i do this?
my example does not work.

```
    map1.emplace(1, 1001);
    map1.emplace(2, 1002);
    map1.emplace(3, 1003);

    map2.emplace(10, 1010);
    map2.emplace(11, 1011);
    map2.emplace(12, 1012);

    map1 = map2;

    cout << map1[1] << endl;
    cout << map1[10] << endl;
    cout << map2[3] << endl;
```

Comment: What's the relation to the upcoming C++20?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I am using C ++ 20

Comment: map1[1] = 0 it does not exist

Comment: And perhaps you should spend a little time reading more about [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and its [assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator%3D) (especially the part where it says "**Replaces** the contents of the container." (emphasis mine)).

Comment: I would have expected you to say keys 1 and 3 no longer reside in `map1` based on that post. So... how about clarifying your question, including what you expect, and what you actually see instead, and [do it in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58057445/edit)

Comment: I need to know how I can do this to save both values, in what way it is possible.

Comment: You might also be interested in reading about [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator), which could help you copy values from one map to another.

Comment: `std::copy(map2.begin(), map2.end(), std::inserter(map1, map1.end()));` , assuming you setup the appropriate includes beforehand, is *likely* what you're trying to do.

Comment: Or `map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end())`.

Comment: @Shawn Yes thanks it looks shorter

Comment: VTC as unclear: you asked at least 4 different questions in the question box and in the three comment sections.

Comment: @YSC I just did not know that by default it does not replace keys, and I need to use a loop

Comment: @Then [edit] your question to make it whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you assign `map2` to `map1`. It copies `map2` into `map1` replacing the old contents.

Therefore after the assignment, the old values are lost and `map1` is now an exact copy of `map2`.

If you want to only add new elements, you can use the [`insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) function instead. This may look as follows:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> map1 {{1 ,1001}, {2, 1002}, {3, 1003}};
    std::map<int, int> map2 {{10, 1010}, {11, 1011}, {12, 1012}};

    map1.insert(map2.cbegin(), map2.cend());

    for(const auto & e : map1)
    {
        std::cout << e.first << ": " << e.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This way, `map2` is inserted into `map1` without erasing the old contents. You just have to know that if you try to insert an already existing key, it will not be inserted (as every elements are unique in `std::map`).

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to replace the already existing values too, you can simply use the [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/). It may look as:

```
for(const auto & e : map2)
{
    // If the key exists, change only the value, add the {key, value} otherwise
    map1[e.first] = e.second;
}
```

Comment: And how to make it replace if the key is the same?

Comment: @Skype I have made an edit to provide you a simple solution.

Comment: For c++17 and up, `insert_or_assign()` is another option (since it doesn't require the mapped type to be default constructible).

Answer (score 0):

You can [`std::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) `map2` into `map1`. If a key is present in `map1`, it will keep its value (regardless of the fact that this key could be in `map2`). If a key is present in `map2` but not in `map1`, it will be copied with its value to `map1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum { ONLY_IN_MAP1, BOTH_IN_MAP1_AND_MAP2, ONLY_IN_MAP2 };

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> map1, map2;

    map1.emplace(ONLY_IN_MAP1, 1);
    map1.emplace(BOTH_IN_MAP1_AND_MAP2, 2);

    map2.emplace(ONLY_IN_MAP2, 3);
    map2.emplace(BOTH_IN_MAP1_AND_MAP2, 4);

    map1.insert(cbegin(map2), cend(map2));

    std::cout << map1[ONLY_IN_MAP1]          << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << map1[BOTH_IN_MAP1_AND_MAP2] << '\n'; // 2
    std::cout << map1[ONLY_IN_MAP2]          << '\n'; // 3
}
```

Demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/571c588e8cee5fb8

Comment: What is the difference between `cbegin` from `begin` and `cend` from `end`
`map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());`
`map1.insert(cbegin(map2), cend(map2));`

Comment: And how to make it replace if the key is the same?

Comment: @Skype ask a more precise question, you'll get a more precise answer.

Comment: @Skype `cbegin()` and `cend()` are `const` iterators to respectively beginning and past-the-end of the container. The difference is that you cannot modify the contents a `const` iterator points to.